# Changes in persistence.xml causes IncompatibleClassChangeError error

Tags: java

When I change my persistence.xml to a JNDI lookup a IncompatibleClassChangeError is being thrown.

This is the one that is working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="report-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>    
        <class>com.citi.listener.model.TATReportItem</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The one that causes the issue is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="report-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.citi.listener.model.TATReportItem</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="X" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="X" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="X" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It's not obvious to me why this is causing the issue?

Comment: Could you highlight the difference?  What change did you make?

Answer (score 0):

Issue here was that the hibernate-entitymanager scope was not set to provided in the pom